# Unsupported URL Protocol (-1)

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode9, xcode-server

I am trying to implement continues integration with xcode server on xcode 9.2

After completing all the steps when i create a new project then under source control its not showing a drop down from where i can select the server that i have created (xcode server), its showing only create git repository on my mac (xcode server is created on my own mac)

After creating the project when we go to create bot section then it says

Creating a bot requires a project that is under source control.

This project does not appear to be in a source control repository that will be accessible by the server. To be able to create a bot, make sure that your project is managed in a source control repository and that the repository is somewhere accessible to the server.

After clicking "Create Working copy" i clicked on Create bot then again it shows below message

Creating a bot requires that the project be under source control that is accessible by the server.

This project appears to be in a local repository. To create a bot, the project must be in a repository that the server can access.

I have added server manually(IP address of my system as xcode server is running on . my server).

But after that when i try to create bot on this server then it does not allow me to go further as it keep showing below error

UnSupported url protocol (-1)

When i try to sign in the nothing happen

I have follow multiple tutorials and following their steps carefully but its giving same error always

Please help